# Button now showing in Relative Layout Android

Tags: android, button

I have added a button in the relative layout but when I run it on the emulator the button does not show.

Here is the xml file

floorplan.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/floorplannextbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: which device are you emulating?

Comment: do you set this layout to setContentView() in your activity?

Comment: @Kay I'm using Google Nexus One -2.3.7

Comment: @SajadGarshasbi yes I did

Comment: same layout renders fine for me on emulator nexus one...

Comment: can u share class file too

Comment: @Kay it was a line of code which i forgot to delete and it was setting a different content view, Thanks for asking to share the class code because that's how I spotted it.